# Error: Looks like you have nested a 'NavigationContainer' inside another

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation

This is the full error:

> Error: Looks like you have nested a NavigationContainer inside another. Normally you need only one container at the root of the app, so this was probably an error. If this was intentional, pass 'independent={true}' explicitly. Note that this will make the child navigators disconnected from the parent and you won't be able to navigate between them.

I don't see why I am getting this error as I only have one NavigationContainer

index.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { useRouter } from 'expo-router';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'

import Home from './home';
import styles from '../myComponents/common/header/header/header.style';
import { COLORS, icons, images, FONT, SIZES } from '../constants';
import { ScreenHeaderBtn, TimeSlider, SessionBtn } from '../myComponents';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
    const router = useRouter();

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};

export default App;
```

home.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Stack, useRouter } from 'expo-router';

import styles from '../myComponents/common/header/header/header.style';
import { COLORS, icons, images, FONT, SIZES } from '../constants';
import { ScreenHeaderBtn, TimeSlider, SessionBtn } from '../myComponents';

const Home = () => {
    const router = useRouter();

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: COLORS.lightBeige }}>
            <Stack.Screen
                options={{
                    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: COLORS.lightBeige },
                    headerShadowVisible: true,
                    headerLeft: () => (
                        <ScreenHeaderBtn iconUrl={icons.menu} dimension="60%" />
                    ),
                    headerTitle: () => (
                        <Text style={styles.headerStyle}>
                            Flowtime
                        </Text>
                    ),
                    headerTitleAlign: 'center',
                }}
            />
            <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: SIZES.medium, }}>

                    <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', padding: SIZES.xLarge }}>
                        <SessionBtn />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', padding: SIZES.xLarge }}>
                        <TimeSlider />
                    </View>

                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

_layout.js

```
import { Stack } from 'expo-router';
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

const Layout = () => {
    const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
        MontBold: require('../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf'),
        MontMed: require('../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf'),
        MontReg: require('../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
    })

    const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
        if(fontsLoaded) {
            await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
        }
    }, [fontsLoaded]
    )

    if(!fontsLoaded) return null;

    return <Stack onLayout={onLayoutRootView}/>;
}

export default Layout;
```

I tried moving the `Stack.Screen` header in `home.js` around into the `NavigationContainer` in index.js but then I get another error that the `Stack.Screen` doesn't have a name or and doesn't have a proper component. I'm not sure how else to fix this error as I only have one `NavigationContainer`. What's even more confusing is that it looks like the React navigation documentation as well.

Comment: Your `Stack.Screen` is not having any Childs and so your `ScrollView` might be seen.. wrap it completely inside that stack screen component? (home.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can set options in index.js. You can refer here.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution/

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options/

```
<NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{
            headerStyle: { backgroundColor: COLORS.lightBeige },
            headerShadowVisible: true,
            headerLeft: () => (
                <ScreenHeaderBtn iconUrl={icons.menu} dimension="60%" />
            ),
            headerTitle: () => (
                <Text style={styles.headerStyle}>
                    Flowtime
                </Text>
            ),
            headerTitleAlign: 'center'
        }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: I edited the code accordingly, but I'm still getting the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete answer.

this should be your **index.js** File

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Home from './home';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Home}
          options={{
            headerTitleAlign: 'center',
            headerTintColor: '#0090FF',
            headerTitleStyle: {
              color: '#000000',
              fontSize: 14,
            },
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            },
            headerShown: true,
            title: 'Home Screen',
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is your **Home.js** File

```
import {SafeAreaView, ScrollView, View} from 'react-native';
import {COLORS, SIZES} from '../constants';
import {SessionBtn, TimeSlider} from '../myComponents';
import React from 'react';
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: COLORS.lightBeige}}>
      <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
        <View style={{flex: 1, padding: SIZES.medium}}>
          <View style={{alignItems: 'center', padding: SIZES.xLarge}}>
            <SessionBtn />
          </View>
          <View style={{alignItems: 'center', padding: SIZES.xLarge}}>
            <TimeSlider />
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

and here is your **_layout.js** File

```
import {useFonts} from 'expo-font';
import {Stack} from 'expo-router';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import {useCallback} from 'react';

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

const Layout = () => {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    MontBold: require('../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf'),
    MontMed: require('../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf'),
    MontReg: require('../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
  });

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (fontsLoaded) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded]);

  if (!fontsLoaded) return null;

  return <Stack onLayout={onLayoutRootView} />;
};

export default Layout;
```